# Shared_ptr never deallocated when boost threads created

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, smart-pointers

So I have a strange situation here. I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClassA> classA = std::shared_ptr<MyClassA>(new MyClassA);
    std::shared_ptr<MyClassB> classB = std::shared_ptr<MyClassB>(new MyClassB(classA));

    boost::thread_group threadGroup;

    // This thread is essentially an infinite loop waiting for data on a socket
    threadGroup.create_thread( boost::bind(&MyClassB::method1, classB) );

    ...do stuff

    return 0;
}
```

MyClassB opens several resources, that are not deallocated when the program exits. However, if I remove the call to create_thread, the resources are deallocated. I put a printout in the destructor of MyClassB, and verified that it's not being called if that thread is created.

Anybody have any insight into what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried joining the threads? Without that, terminating the program might skip destructors of non-global objects. That said, why don't you create a minimal example instead of paraphrasing what you did in order to analyze the issue? Oh, I forgot: Use `std::thread` instead!

Comment: I believe that boost threads get detached in their destructors.

Comment: what is the signature of `MyClassB::method1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation `boost::thread_group` destructor destroys all onwed thread. `boost::thread` destructor in order:

> - if defined BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE: If *this has an associated thread of execution, calls detach(), DEPRECATED
> - BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE: If the thread is joinable calls to std::terminate. Destroys *this.

So you need to join threads explicitly. You can do that by calling `boost::thread_group::join_all()` at the end of your program.

Comment: Good advice. Added a mechanism for the thready to exit gracefully, and the resources were freed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are passing shared pointer to class B to your thread, your thread now shares the instance. Until this threads exits NATURALLY, this resource will not be freed.

Answer (score 1):

> `// This thread is essentially an infinite loop waiting for data on a socket`

This comment is very telling. Your thread may run forever, well past the end of the program. If that's the case, you need to detach the thread before you exit main, and you should expect not to see the destructor called. The thread is still alive and shares ownership of that object.

> `...do stuff`

If that `...do stuff` doesn't involve either detaching or joining that thread, you are invoking undefined behavior in Boost. That undefined behavior becomes very well defined if you switch from using `boost::thread` to using `std::thread`.

That well-defined behavior is something that no sane programmer wants to invoke: Destructing a joinable thread results in a call to `std::terminate()`. The behavior of `std::terminate` is implementation-dependent, but typically it means "stop right now". Destructors aren't called, exit handlers aren't called.

You need to either join or detach that thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My experience with multithreaded programming is pretty minimal, trying to debug an error in a program I inherited (ugh). I wasn't aware that the thread wasn't destroyed at the exit of the program. Added a mechanism to join the thread at the end of the program. It exits gracefully, and resources are returned.